# Don't add Bearer verification

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, swagger

I have created an asp.net core project now, and I am making a swagger verification token, all of which are fine, but how to verify without adding the beginning of Bearer, what should I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8myT6.png)

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? For example, what do you mean by "verify without adding the beginning of Bearer"? As currently written, it's unclear what you are trying to do. It would also help if you posted your current code and explained how you tried to solve the issue and where you got stuck.

Comment: I use swagger to verify the token, and I need to enter Bearer at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to omit the "Bearer" prefix tag, you can do this:

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(config =>
            {   
                      ////Name the security scheme
                config.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    // Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                    Scheme = "bearer",
                    BearerFormat="JWT"
                });

                config.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,

           //The name of the previously defined security scheme.
                Id = "Bearer"
            }

        },
        new List<string>()
    }
});
```

> Note : If using SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey – token part should be
> appended with ‘bearer’.
>
> Note – If using SecuritySchemeType.Http – token need to be used
> without “bearer”

Result:

[image]

Comment: Oh yeah yeah, that's it！！